# Function name must be string error when trying to hide div

Tags: php, fatal-error

I am attempting to hide a div when a specific value is posted. I want to be able to echo the additional css in the style="" of a div. I get the following error when I do so:

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/bryantrx/public_html/wo/or/wo_add.php on line 185

Here is my code from line 185:

```
<div <?php if (!$_POST('JobTypeDDL') == "New Mobility"){echo "style='display:none;'";}?>>test</div>
```

If there is an alternative way of doing this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` is an *associative array* [super global](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), not a *function*.

#### Wrong:

```
$_POST('JobTypeDDL')
```

#### Right:

```
$_POST['JobTypeDDL']
```

**Note:** I encourage you to read through the [PHP types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php).

Comment: Even though it is Tuesday it feels like a Monday. Thanks my mind has been elsewhere and didn't catch it.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing `$_POST` with wrong brackets: use square ones:

```
$_POST['JobTypeDDL']
```

With your syntax, PHP thinks you are trying to call a function called with the value of `$_POST` [which is an array] with `JobTypeDDL` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use this fixed code:

```
<div <?php if($_POST['JobTypeDDL'] == 'New Mobility') { echo "style='display:none;'"; } ?>>test</div>
```

The problem with your code was that $_POST('JobTypeDDL') should be $_POST['JobTypeDDL'].

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this,

```
<div <?php if (!$_POST['JobTypeDDL'] == "New Mobility"){echo "style='display:none;'";}?>>test</div>
```

`$_POST` is an array, not a function.